# Is it dangerous to pipe data from S3 to a long-running process

Tags: linux, amazon-s3

I have a 30GB file and I want to feed it into a program that accepts data via stdin and that will take 24hr to process the data.

Can I just do `aws s3 cp s3://bigfile.txt - | long_process.sh`?

I'm attracted to this b/c I don't have to store bigfile.txt on disk and I can start working on the data stream immediately, but I worry that if the s3 command has a problem during the 24 hours that it will crash and I will lose all the progress.

EDIT:

Alternatively, I am looking for a way to stage the data to a file and read from the staged data.  For example: `aws s3 cp s3://bigfile.txt /local/bigfile.txt &; long_process.sh < /local/bigfile.txt`.  The trouble is that long_process.sh complains of a truncated file; It does not seem to wait for further input like a pipe would.  I have thought about `tee` and `mkfifo` but nothing seems to quite fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s dangerous because the processing might crash during the time and you could lose everything